# Best way to color <a> tags?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

In jQM 1.4, I have a listview containing a bunch of listitems, each structured like this:

```
<li>
    <a>
        <input type="checkbox">
        <label>
           ...
        </label>
    </a>
    <a></a>
</li>
```

I want to change the background color of both `<A>` tags to yellow if the visible listitem's checkbox is checked, and white if it is not checked (I specify visible because listitems may be filtered out, and I don't want to affect those listitems).  This is the code I use to do this:

```
$("#lvMain li input[type=checkbox]:visible:not(:checked)").closest("li").find("a").css({"background":"white"});
$("#lvMain li input[type=checkbox]:visible:checked").closest("li").find("a").css({"background":"yellow"});
```

This does work, but I am interested to know if there is a better way because this seems kinda expensive.

Thanks!

Comment: You are putting block elements into your anchor? Why?

Comment: @AlexShilman: It's perfectly valid to put block elements in an anchor. The [content model of `a` elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element) is transparent, so in the above, anything that's allowed in an `li` is allowed in the `a` within it. I'll grant you that putting a checkbox in them seems...odd. That said, both `input` and `label` are *phrasing* content, not flow content, so not really "block" elements anyway.

Comment: you want a js solution or css? http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/XUjEV/

Comment: I simplified the html for brevity, but the `LI` ends up being a listitem with a checkbox that is just on the left of of the `LI`, as opposed to the whole listitem being the checkbox.  When I click the checkbox, I need to change the background color of both `A` tags.  There are several "listview with checkboxes" examples out there, but I had to adapt to work with 1.4 and also just have the left portion of the listitem the checkbox, not the whole thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your markup seems a bit awkward. If you're able to change it to this:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <a>Foo</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

You could simply do this in CSS:

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ a {
  background: yellow;
}
```

**[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/USApeCEr/1/edit)**

Otherwise, your js isn't all that bad. It is not likely to hurt anything performance wise.

Comment: Assuming the OP doesn't have to support IE8. I don't *think* IE8 has the [general sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#general-sibling-combinators), just the [adjacent sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors). (That said, you could use the adjacent sibling combinator -- `+` -- with your markup above.)

Comment: @Omar I wasn't suggesting it is invalid, just awkward :)

Comment: @m59: Thanks for the reply.  While I agree that the code seems awkward, as far as I've been able to develop, it's the only way the acheive the checkbox-effect I desire.  To use CSS, I'd have to get the parent of the `input`.  From what I have read, I could use a CSS solution with CSS4, but that'll have to wait.  [Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrphuzz/fhF99/) to show the effect.

Comment: @m59: Additioally, while your suggested re-code wouldn't work in my situation, as I read the rest of the comments, I select your answer as the answer due to the "not likely to hurt" part, as I haven't seen any other contrary comments to suggest a hurtful performance.

Comment: @mrphuzz Those are expensive selections, but the effects of that only become obvious when you use them within a large context. You wouldn't want to do that 10,000 times at once, for example.